# Python unable to connect to spark for debugging

Tags: python, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am running a spark python program and need to debug the application. I did a spark-submit and my spark is waiting on a debug port to be connected.

I have my application in Intellij. Created a remote python debug configuration and tried to attach that to the spark listening port but it says

```
Failed to find free socket port
```

Let me know what is the issue here.

Comment: Yes, but this did not solved my issue.

Comment: @Nipun to avoid duplicated content. I suggest that you reply on the original question. I'd gladly upvote your answer but I'm closing this one as a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve this. You need to start the intellij debugger first, let it wait for someone to connect on the debugger and then do a spark submit. Also add the lines in the beginning of your code

```
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace('localhost', port=7777, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
```